# Connect Excel to Google Sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I'm using Excel to create a form that is linked to another sheet that acts as a database.

This is my form (worksheet's name : "Form"):

[image]

And this is part of the database (worksheet's name: "Data"):

[image]

Right now it connects using a VBA script that is activated using the "save" button (green). Here's  parts of the script:

```
Private Sub destBook()
    setFormBook

    If (destinationBook Is Nothing) Then
        Dim file As String
        file = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("_options").Cells(2, 26).Value //"path/to/the/database/file.xlsx"
        If (IsEmpty(file)) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("_options").Select
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("_options").Cells(2, 26).Select
            Dim m As VbMsgBoxResult
            m = MsgBox("")
        Else
            Set destinationBook = Workbooks.Open(file)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub SaveClick()
    Dim dataIdx As Integer
    dataIdx = GetIdx()

    If (dataIdx >= 2) Then
        destBook
        
        If (hasLock() = False) Then
            WarnNoLock
            closeDst
        Else
            Dim mappingRng  As Range: Set mappingRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("_mappings").Range("F2:F71")

            Dim rowIdx As Integer
        
            For rowIdx = 1 To mappingRng.Rows.count
                Dim FormRange As Range
                Set FormRange = mappingRng.Cells(RowIndex:=rowIdx, ColumnIndex:=1)
                If FormRange <> "" Then
                    Dim dataCol As Integer
                    Dim newValue As String
                    dataCol = mappingRng.Cells(RowIndex:=rowIdx, ColumnIndex:=2)
                    newValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range(FormRange).Value
                    destinationBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(dataIdx, dataCol).Value = newValue
                End If
            Next
            
            ' refresh
            Application.CalculateFull
        End If
    
        ' close & save
        closeDst
    End If

End Sub
```

My question : Instead of saving/re-writing the data (Form) to another Excel file (Data), is it possible to save/re-write the data (Form) to a Google Sheet document ?

My guess would be to use the sharing link, but not sure how to make it works.

Comment: What is the benefit of using excel? Isn't it simplier to use google sheet for all the project?

Comment: Yes and no. The organization wanted to keep using Excel. I wanted to try working around some problems I encountered with OneDrive and GoogleDrive synchronization option.

Comment: (je suis français aussi, mais continuons en Anglais c'est la règle ici) when you say `I'm using Excel to create a form` did you create the form whith excel or did you create the data ? What I did'nt really undestand is what in your idea is in excel and what is in gogole sheets and/or google forms ?

Comment: I created the "form" using Excel (but it's actually just a table that looks like a form). When you save the "form" it writes the data in a table located in a different file. The idea is/was that this second file is located in a local OneDrive folder that is shared by 3 users. Since OneDrive has problems synching I wanted to write the data directly to a Google Sheets.

Comment: I have never had the experience of writing on Google Sheet by a third party app. You can maybe take a look in Sheetsu, Sheet2api or, I think it could be a better way, using python that you can lunch by VBA. The best way is probably to export the data by json. Reading from a spreadsheet is relatively easy by the endpoint.

Comment: for Python, you can learn a bit more here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Another way could be to create a form linked to a spreadsheet and fill the form by Excel using sendkeys. But py could be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

you can import JsonConverter.bas into your project (Open VBA Editor, Alt + F11; File > Import File) from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases
and make table in your excel sheet, input this code to your module

```
Sub ConnectSheets()
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 'To use POST http Request
'Get data table as JSON
tableData = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Sheets("Page1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Value)
' 'Create All Json to Send
Data = "{""dataReq"": " & vbNewLine & tableData & vbNewLine & ", " & vbNewLine & " ""fname"":""pasteData""}"
Debug.Print Data
'Define the google URL
myurl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzE0nm-Jz2yE4IWc7OB_ter8NrNKBL9SXuxi6cG74FeUpwCx6T9tFZyPd13dRxgaqEm/exec"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False 'define method to use
xmlhttp.Send Data 'execute call
sGetResult = xmlhttp.ResponseText 'read response
Debug.Print sGetResult 'view response
End Sub
```

and put code to your google sheet, apply as webapp

```
function doPost(request = {}) {
const { parameter, postData: { contents, type } = {} } = request; //request data
const { dataReq = {} } = JSON.parse(contents); //content
const { fname = {} } = JSON.parse(contents); //function name
const response = {
status: "function not found: " + fname, // prepare response in function not found
data2: dataReq
}
switch (fname) { //function selection
case 'pasteData':
var output = JSON.stringify(pasteData(dataReq)) //call function with data, name and type from request
break
default:
var output = JSON.stringify(response)
break
}
return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); //response to frontend
}
function pasteData(dataReq) {
const id = '1wtGM5QL0LwIYJoU9joOO31n_kBbJJJHRFaKtIdwWOeU'; //id of Google Sheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('Page1'); //sheet
sheet.clear(); //delete data
sheet.getRange(1, 1, dataReq.length, dataReq[0].length).setValues(dataReq); // paste new data
return "Numbers of sheets added: "+ dataReq.length; //return a response
}
```